# How to get the maxDepth from a Spark RandomForestRegressionModel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

In Spark (2.1.0) I've used a `CrossValidator` to train a `RandomForestRegressor`, using `ParamGridBuilder` for `maxDepth` and `numTrees`:

```py
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(rf.maxDepth, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]) \
    .addGrid(rf.numTrees, [10, 20, 40, 50]) \
    .build()
```

After training, I can get the best number of trees:

```py
regressor = cvModel.bestModel.stages[len(cvModel.bestModel.stages) - 1]

print(regressor.getNumTrees)
```

but I can't work out how to get the best maxDepth. I've read the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel) and I don't see what I'm missing.

I'd note that I can iterate through all the trees and find the depth of each one, eg

```py
regressor.trees[0].depth
```

This seems like I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately PySpark `RandomForestRegressionModel` before Spark 2.3, unlike its Scala counterpart, doesn't store upstream `Estimator` `Params`, but you should be able to retrieve it directly from the JVM object. With a simple monkey patch:

```py
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressionModel

RandomForestRegressionModel.getMaxDepth = (
    lambda self: self._java_obj.getMaxDepth()
)
```

you can:

```py
cvModel.bestModel.stages[-1].getMaxDepth()
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler, just call

```
    cvModel.bestModel.stages[-1]._java_obj.getMaxDepth()
```

As @user6910411 explained, you get the bestModel, call the JVM object of this model and extract your parameter using getMaxDepth() from the JVM object.
Similar works for other parameters.